# Ошибка при попытке создать проект c# в visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

При попытке создать проект C# в visual studio 2015 выходит окно с ошибкой следующего содержания, "Ошибка при записи в файл проекта. Класс не зарегистрирован"?? До этого не было никаких проблем. Что это может быть?

Comment: Вы бы хоть уточнили какой тип проекта создаете. Может вы пытаетесь создать проект в папку, в которой у вас нет доступа на запись?

Comment: Пробовал и консольное и windows form, ошибка все равно остается. Пробовал и в разные папки, не помогает.(

Comment: Ну, тогда попробуйте переустановить студию.

Comment: Проще всего и правда переустановить студию. То есть в логах там где-то есть наверняка точная причина проблемы, но копаться в них — то ещё удовольствие.

Comment: @VladD, переустановка студии редко от таких проблем помогает...

Comment: @Qwertiy: Хм, а что помогает? Ну не систему ж переставлять?

Comment: @VladD, ничего не помогает... Точнее, помогает замена создания нового проекта на копирование существующего старого того же типа и его открытие. По необходимости ещё и гуиды ручками поменять. А так, да - систему... Уж не знаю, на что они там завязались, но не слышал историй, чтобы кому-то удалось починить...

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ыыыыы! Звучит пессимистично. А нету баграпорта в connect'е? Это ж серьёзный баг как бы.

Comment: @VladD, редко встречается, не знаю. Мне попадалоь дважды, в VS2010 для asp.net mvc (другие типы создавались) - мне тогда тем компом оставалось пару недель пользоваться и дома в VS2013 - просто поставил свежевышедшую VS2015 и забил. Ещё пару раз слышал подобные истории. И ещё слышал, что VS2017 (вроде rc, не уверен) ломалась и ломала VS2015 за компанию, что исправлялось только переустановкой системы - но не уверен, как именно это проявлялось.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно стоит поменять "Целевую платформу" (я менял на х86).

Project>Project_name Properties>Build>Platform target

Понятия не имею с чем это связано, но уже не первый раз такое случается.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй установить [MSXML 6.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/ru-ru/details.aspx?FamilyID=d21c292c-368b-4ce1-9dab-3e9827b70604).

Проблема связана с отсутствием или повреждением MSXML пакета. Аналогичный вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262520/visual-studio-bug-error-writing-the-project-file-class-not-registered